# How do I make running Maven modules in parallel run just as fast as running them individually?

Tags: maven, junit, parallel-processing, maven-3, integration-testing

I’m using Maven 3.2.3, Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE, JUnit 4.11, Java 6, and the Surefire/Failsafe 2.17 plugins.  I’m trying to figure out why when running a couple of modules in parallel, it takes much longer than when I run them individually.  I’m trying to figure out ways to speed up my build.  I have this in my parent pom …

```
    <modules>
            <module>main</module>
            … 
            <module>module-x</module>
            <module>module-y</module>
    </modules>
```

When I run “mvn clean install -T 2”, modules “module-x” and “module-y” run in parallel.  Both have a number of integration tests, all using

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
    @ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:test-context.xml" }) 
    public class MyServiceIT 
    {
```

Below are my surefire/failsafe configurations …

```
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.17</version>
                            <configuration>
                                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                                    <argLine>-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M </argLine>
                                    <skipTests>${skipAllTests}</skipTests>
                            </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.17</version>
                            <configuration>
                                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                                    <argLine>-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M </argLine>
                                    <skipTests>${skipAllTests}</skipTests>
                            </configuration>
                            <executions>
                                    <execution>
                                            <goals>
                                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                    </execution>
                            </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

When I run the tests in parallel, the modules take 11 minutes and 13 minutes, respectively, to run.  However, running them concurrently (without the “-T” option), they execute in 6 minutes and 9 minutes, respectively.  I’m confused about why they take so much longer to run when they both run at the same time and was hoping some folks could suggest some ways I can troubleshoot this further.

Comment: Try adding `<forkCount>2.5C</forkCount>` . On a Quad core it allows to have 10 process executing test, and on a Duo it will allows to have 5 process. And from Surefire docs : "The default setting is forkCount=1/reuseForks=true, which means that Surefire creates one new JVM process to execute all tests in one maven module." So maybe try `<reuseFork>false</reuseFork>`and check the execution time.

Comment: A basic question but sometimes these are worth checking: do you have enough CPU & RAM to run both modules simultaneously? i.e. when the modules test in 6 and 9 minutes respectively, do you still have half your CPUs idle and when they run in parallel is there any memory pressure?